# google map v2 stackoverflowererror device Nexus7

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, stack-overflow

Please help me.
Why android google map v2 stack overflowerror?

android version 4.3 nexus7

Does it happen only on this device? -> yes

Is this the whole code?             -> yes

zoomLevel 15 and tokyo station      -> stackoverflowerror happen

Here is my code:

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
          setContentView(R.layout.globalpositioningsystem_adv_main);

    Log.d("onCreate","onCreate");
          setUpMapIfNeeded();
   }


private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    Log.d("setUpMapIfNeeded","setUpMapIfNeeded");

    if (map == null) {
        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (map != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}


private void setUpMap() {
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomGesturesEnabled(true);
    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

}
```

Here is my xml code:

```html
  <fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
     />
```

This error messages:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1393
>      java.lang.StackOverflowError
>      at maps.at.ba.b(Unknown Source)
>      at maps.at.ba.a(Unknown Source)
>      at maps.h.q.e(Unknown Source)
>      at maps.h.q.f(Unknown Source)

This Thread messages:
Thread [<31> GLThread 4064] (Suspended (exception StackOverflowError))

> this  af  (id=830044410896)
>           a false
>       b   true
>       c   false
>       contextClassLoader  LoadedApk$WarningContextClassLoader  (id=830044221600)
>       d   false
>       daemon  false
>       e   true
>       f   false
>       g   false
>       group   ThreadGroup  (id=830029862656)
>       h   false
>       hasBeenStarted  true
>       i   false
>       id  4064
>       inheritableValues   null
>       interruptActions    ArrayList  (id=830038471784)
>       j   false
>       k   800 
>       l   1053
>       localValues ThreadLocal$Values  (id=830038946536)
>       m   0
>       n   true
>       name    "GLThread 4064" (id=830038884576)
>       o   true
>       p   ArrayList  (id=830043209400)
>       parkBlocker null
>       parkState   1
>       priority    5
>       q   false
>       r   ae  (id=830037523264)
>       s   WeakReference  (id=830043387808)
>       stackSize   0
>       target  null
>       uncaughtHandler null
>       vmThread    VMThread  (id=830043209456)

Comment: check your google Play is install or updated in your device?

Comment: check your google Play is install or updated in your device? check google play,update end, no problem